# Windows 10 UWP, back button to previous Frame with hamburger menu

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

I changed menu available only in first page in my application to hamburger menu. Now it's available in all pages.

Problem now is with my hardware button on phone. Previously it's worked good from this solution:
http://devcenter.wintellect.com/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps

Now I have first page (root) which load to "frame"(splitview.content) main page. And now when I press from menu other page( in my example "Products") and press "back" button on my phone, application is shutting down. I think because application didn't know that is in "frame" page, but it's still on root frame, so back button is closing application

I don't know how to handle this

I'm sending my example:
[example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ZmP3NVyVJkNFRhQzJVWl82WGM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, what you need to do is to subscribe to the `Navigated` event on `MyFrame` instead of subscribing to that event on `rootFrame`, subscribe the `BackRequested` event in your `root` page and instead of trying to back-navigate `rootFrame`, back-navigate `MyFrame`. So the code in your `root` page could look like this:

XAML:

```
<Frame Name="MyFrame" Navigated="MyFrame_Navigated"/>
```

C#:

```
public root()
{
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
}

private void MyFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
            MyFrame.CanGoBack ?
            AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
            AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
}

private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MyFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

You should also remove all the code related to the `rootFrame`'s back navigation in your `App.xaml.cs` because it's not needed for back navigation in custom frame.

And next time, please post the related code in your question. It will be easier to read :)

Comment: Thanks it works really better, but now it's some other problem. Problem or not but, now I really don't know if this behaviour is right or not:)

Let's say that I have this hierarchy of pages:

          Main
             |
Persons   Products
      |                |
 EditPer      EditPro

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter by mistake.
It's working good when I choose Products, then from Products click Edit. When I press back It backs in good way. The problem is when I am for example on EditProduct Page and press from menu "Persons". Then when I press back button it comes back to "EditProductPage", not to "parent" page of Products, which is "Main". 
I'm really don't know if this is right behaviour. But in my actual application I have little more pages and when I test this operation several time it creates strange "queue" of previous pages.
If You want I can send You my whole project

Comment: Then it will be easier to not show the hamburger menu on Edit page so user will must click for example Cancel/Save button to go back to Products page where he could use the hamburger menu.

Comment: You can achieve that by navigating rootFrame to the Edit page. You should also implement the logic for back-navigation of rootFrame again in App.xaml.cs so it can go back to the page with hamburger menu.

Comment: Ok. It's good point. I will try. I have only one question. How is the simplest way to hide my menu only for specific pages (or the best -  whole TopAppBar with button to open it, which is defined in root page).

Comment: You could make a public method in the root page that will set the Visibility of the CommandBar in TopAppBar based on some bool parameter. You'll also need to store the root page instance somewhere, f.e. in public static property of type root that you'll set in your root page constructor to be 'this'.

Comment: Please post a new question for questions not really related to the original one for better readability.

Comment: This answer helped me to understand frame navigation in relation to the global back button. I found the concept for implementing this in the `App` class can be applied to any custom frame. +1 for you!